# Split value of cell and replicate the whole row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering which Google Apps Script function may help me to split a Google Sheets cell value into `n` parts (given a separator) and replicate the whole row as different occurrences for that split. So, f.i., given this table:

| Name | Country | Sport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | USA | Basketball_Golf_Tennis |
| Mary | Canada | Tennis_Golf |

the desired output should be:

| Name | Country | Sport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | USA | Basketball |
| John | USA | Golf |
| John | USA | Tennis |
| Mary | Canada | Tennis |
| Mary | Canada | Golf |

In this example, the separator is the char `_`

Comment: Wait, is this not for google sheets? My function will still work, but I was thinking you were using sheets.

Comment: @pgSystemTester, yes this is for Google Sheets :)

Comment: Ok well that will obviously work, however I bet this could be done without app scripts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably do this with a regular spreadsheet formula (lookout for incoming solution from [Player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) who will probably point out something I should have thought of... ), but since you asked for an app script solution, this works:

```
/**
 * Splits data
 *
 * @param {array} theRange The range of data.
 * @param {string} theSplitter The text used to split.
 * @return the new table
 * @customfunction
 */
function goUSA(theRange, theSplitter) {
  const splitColumn = 2;

  var result = [];
  for (r = 0; r < theRange.length; r++) {
    var aRow = theRange[r];

    //skips empty rows, enabling ability to select entire column
    if (aRow.join('') != '') {
      var tempSplit = aRow[splitColumn].split(theSplitter);
      for (q = 0; q < tempSplit.length; q++) {
        result.push([aRow[0], aRow[1], tempSplit[q]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

see:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(C1:C, "_"))="",, 
 A1:A&"​"&B1:B&"​"&SPLIT(C1:C, "_"))), "​"), "where Col2 is not null", ))
```

[image]

Comment: There it is... this will perform faster than an app script solution.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting Column 3

```
function brkaprt() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  osh.clearContents();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let obj = {pA:[]};
  let o = vs.reduce((ac,[a,b,c],i) => {
    c.split("_").forEach(e =>ac.push([a,b,e]) )
    return ac;
  },[]);
  o.unshift(["Name","Country","Sport"]);  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  osh.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);

}

Execution log
10:56:15 AM Notice  Execution started
10:56:16 AM Info    [["Name","Country","Sport"],["John","USA","Basketball"],["John","USA","Golf"],["John","USA","Tennis"],["Mary","Canada","Tennis"],["Mary","Canada","Golf"]]
10:56:17 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Country | Sport |
| 2 | John | USA | Basketball |
| 3 | John | USA | Golf |
| 4 | John | USA | Tennis |
| 5 | Mary | Canada | Tennis |
| 6 | Mary | Canada | Golf |